# MySQL Group by multiple columns where there are duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a fairly simple schema, with rows like

[image]

What I'm trying to do is group the results by `name` then `sku` - only where there are duplicates.

For example, my expected results would be

```
sku1 | Blue T-shirt
sku1 | Dark Blue T-shirt
sku2 | Red T-Shirt
sku2 | Reddish T-shirt
```

`sku3` is not returned, because they all have the same name.

I have tried

```
SELECT
  sku, 
  name, 
  count(*) 
FROM 
  order_items
GROUP BY
  name, 
  sku
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, this omits `sku2`

```
sku  | name          | count(*)
sku1 | Blue T-shirt  | 3
sku2 | Green T-shirt | 3
```

`count(*)` in this case seems to be returning the total rows, before grouping.

I've got a SQL fiddle of this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532d37/9

Comment: yes that wgat grouping by two values does and it is correct in that regard

Comment: and count(*) > 1 means 2 or more must be present for your expected result bith additional only a present one

Comment: and you result6 in your dbfiddle shows sk1 and sku3 not sku 2

Comment: @nbk fixed typo in question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will meet expected result.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT c.sku, c.name
FROM order_items c
INNER JOIN (SELECT sku
                 , COUNT(DISTINCT name) dis_cnt
            FROM order_items
            GROUP BY sku
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1) t
        ON c.sku = t.sku 
GROUP BY c.sku, c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN with the same table.

```
SELECT
  order_items.sku, 
  order_items.name 
FROM
  order_items
 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
  sku, 
  name, 
  count(*) 
FROM 
  order_items
GROUP BY
  name, 
  sku
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) A
ON
  order_items.sku = A.sku
```